# Parsing JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, json, reinventing-the-wheel

I need to write some JavaScript code that will take a JSON string, parse it, and return the names of the most-deeply nested properties. For example, for this input:

```
var json = 
"{\
foo: {\
  bar: 'something',\
  baz: {\
    jack: 'other',\
  },\
  bob: {\
    bill: 'hello',\
    bilbo: 11,\
      baggins: {\
        fizz: 'buzz'\
        finger: 'bang'\
      }\
    }\
  }\
}";
```

it should return `['fizz', 'finger']`. There are a couple of caveats:

- the parsing must be done "manually"- i.e. I can't use `eval` or a JS library to parse the JSON
- the JSON property values are guaranteed to be strings, numbers, or objects, i.e. no arrays

Here's what I've come up with so far. The main function is `findDeepestLeaveNodes`. At the moment the code is a bit inefficient as it has to iterate twice over the whole input String. I'd like to improve this if possible, and am also looking for suggestions for improving the code quality.

```
var constants = {
    BLOCK_START: '{',
    BLOCK_END: '}'
};

function findDeepestLeaveNodes(json) {

    var maxNesting = getMaxNesting(json);
    var currentNestLevel = 0;
    var results = [];
    var jsonLength = json.length;

    for (var currentCharIndex = 0; currentCharIndex < jsonLength; currentCharIndex++) {
        var currentChar = json.charAt(currentCharIndex);        
        //console.log("Nesting level " + currentNestLevel + " at character '" + currentChar + "'");

        if (currentChar == constants.BLOCK_START) {

            // FIXME The following parsing is fairly fragile. It doesn't handle the possibility
            // that a '}' or ',' way occur inside a String and therefore do always close a block or
            // separate sibling JSON properties. To handle this we'd need to write a proper JSON parser.
            if (++currentNestLevel == maxNesting) {             
                // read the content of the current block
                var blockEndIndex = json.indexOf(constants.BLOCK_END, currentCharIndex);
                var currentBlock = json.substring(currentCharIndex + 1, blockEndIndex);

                // Each position in the properties array will contain a property name and it's value
                var properties = currentBlock.split(',');

                for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                    // parse out the property name
                    var property = properties[i];
                    var separatorPosition = properties[i].indexOf(':');
                    var propertyName = property.substring(0, separatorPosition);

                    results.push(propertyName.trim());
                }               
            }           
        } else if (currentChar == constants.BLOCK_END) {            
            --currentNestLevel;
        }                   
    }
    return results;
}

function getMaxNesting(json) {
    var jsonlength = json.length;
    var currentNestLevel = 0;
    var maxNestLevel = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonlength; i++) {
        var currentChar = json.charAt(i);

        if (currentChar == constants.BLOCK_START) {
            ++currentNestLevel;

        } else if (currentChar == constants.BLOCK_END) {            
            // update maxNestLevel if necessary
            maxNestLevel = Math.max(currentNestLevel, maxNestLevel);
            --currentNestLevel;
        }       
    }   
    return maxNestLevel;
}
```

Comment: Technically that isn't valid JSON, the keys aren't strings since they don't have quotes around them.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use library code?

Answer (score 3):

I'd write it as a recursive descent parser since this is quite simple:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Actually I already did this a couple of years back, when I wanted to create something that simply formats and highlights JSON a bit. If you can understand it, then you can modify it to your needs:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
.str
{
    color: green;
}

.obj
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.num
{
    color: red;
}
        </style>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
  result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) result += this;
  return result;
}

function jsonFormater() {
  this.reset = function() {
    this.txt = '';
    this.pos = 0;
    this.result = '';
    this.indent = 0;
    this.classes = Array();
  };

  this.undoindent = function() {
    this.indent -= 4;
    this.nline();
  };

  this.doindent = function() {
    this.indent += 4;
    this.nline();
  };

  this.nline = function() {
    this.result += '<br />' + '&nbsp;'.repeat(this.indent);
  };

  this.chClass = function(neu) {
    if (this.classes.length > 0) this.result += '</span>';
    this.result += '<span class="' + neu + '">';
    this.classes.push(neu);
  };

  this.endClass = function() {
    this.classes.pop();
    this.result += '</span>';
    if (this.classes.length > 0) this.result += '<span class="' + this.classes[this.classes.length - 1] + '">';
  };

  this.formatJson = function(txt) {
    this.txt = txt;
    this.pos = 0;
    this.result = '';
    while (this.pos < this.txt.length) {
      if (this.txt[this.pos] == '{') this.parseObj();
      else if (this.txt[this.pos] =='[') this.parseArray();
      this.pos++;
    }

    return this.result;
  }

  this.parseObj = function(ende) {
    if (typeof ende =='undefined') var ende = '}';
    this.chClass('obj');

    do {
      if ((this.txt[this.pos] == '{') || (this.txt[this.pos] == '[')) this.nline();
      this.result += this.txt[this.pos];
      if (this.txt[this.pos] == ',') this.nline();
      if ((this.txt[this.pos] == '{') || (this.txt[this.pos] == '[')) this.doindent();
      this.pos++;
      if (this.txt[this.pos] == '{') this.parseObj();
      if (this.txt[this.pos] == '[') this.parseArray();
      if (this.txt[this.pos] == '"') this.parseString();
      if (/\d/.test(this.txt[this.pos])) this.parseNum();
      if ((this.txt[this.pos] == '}') || (this.txt[this.pos] == ']')) this.undoindent();
    } while ((this.pos < this.txt.length) && (this.txt[this.pos] != ende));

    this.result += this.txt[this.pos];
    this.pos++;
    this.endClass();
  };

  this.parseArray = function() {
    this.parseObj(']');
  };

  this.parseString = function() {
    this.chClass('str');
    do {
      this.result += this.htmlEscape(this.txt[this.pos]);
      this.pos++;
    } while ((this.pos < this.txt.length) && ((this.txt[this.pos] != '"') || (this.txt[this.pos - 1] == '\\')));

    this.result += this.htmlEscape(this.txt[this.pos]);
    this.pos++;
    this.endClass();
  };

  this.parseNum = function() {
    this.chClass('num');
    do {
      this.result += this.txt[this.pos];
      this.pos++;
    } while ((this.pos < this.txt.length) && (/[\d\.]/.test(this.txt[this.pos])));

    this.endClass();
  };

  this.htmlEscape = function(txt) {
    return txt.replace(/&/,'&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
  };

  this.reset();
}

var parser = new jsonFormater();

function go(txt) {
  document.getElementById('ausgabe').innerHTML = parser.formatJson(txt);
  parser.reset();
}

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="go(document.getElementById('thetextarea').value);">
        <textarea id="thetextarea" rows="25" cols="70" onKeyUp="go(this.value);">[{"Dies":"Ist ein Beispiel...","mit":["Arrays","und","so"]},{"alles":"sch&ouml;n verschachtelt..."},"tippt einfach json-zeugs in dem grossen Feld.","Die Anzeige aktualisiert sich sofort...","Die Formatierungen sind als &lt;style&gt; gespeichert. Ihr k&ouml;nnt sie so beliebig &auml;ndern.",{"Zahlen":1,"sind":[1,4,55.67],"auch":"sch&ouml;n"}]</textarea>
        <div id="ausgabe"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in two steps:

1. Parse the json
2. Find the deepest node of that object.

When you separate your code like that, you wind up with two reusable functions instead of one single-use function, which is always a good thing.

I wrote the json parser as a self executing anonymous function that returns an object. What this does is encapsulate all the helper functions so they aren't exposed to outside functions and results in a object with just one method: `decode`.

```js
var JSON = (function() {
    function charIsLetter(c) {
        return ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z');
    }
    function charIsNumber(c) {
        return '0' <= c && c <= '9';
    }

    function decodeInt(s) {
        for ( //iterate through the string while it is a number
            var i = 0, c = s.charAt(0);
            i < s.length && charIsNumber(c);
            c = s.charAt(++i)
        );

        //return [integer, the rest of the string]
        return [parseInt(s.substring(0,i), 10), s.substring(i)];
    }

    function decodeString(s) {
        var q = s.charAt(0), //what quotation wraps the string?
            str = "";

        for (var i=1;i<s.length;i++) { //iterate through the string
            c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c == "\\") {//if the next quotation is escaped, skip it
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            if (c == q)
                return [str, s.substring(i+1)]; //return [the string, what comes after it]

            str += c;
        }

        throw "String doesn't have closing quote ("+q+") at: " + s;
    }

    function decodeObject(s) {
        s = s.substring(1); //remove first {
        var ob = {}, key, val;

        while (true) {
            if (s.length == 0)
                throw "Reached end of string while looking for '}'";

            s = s.replace(/^\s+/m, ""); //remove excess whitespace

            if (s.charAt(0) == "}")
                return [ob, s.substring(1)]; //return the object and what's left over

            key = decode2(s); //key = [decoded string/number/etc, string remaining]
            s = key[1].substring(1); //s is now the leftovers, remove ":"

            val = decode2(s); //val = [decoded string/number/etc, string remaining]
            s = val[1]; //s is now the leftovers

            if (s.charAt(0) == ",") //if there is a comma after the value, remove it
                s = s.substring(1);

            ob[key[0]] = val[0];
        }
    }

    function decodeImproperString(s) {
        for ( //iterate the string while the character is a letter
            var i = 0, c = s.charAt(0);
            i < s.length && charIsLetter(c);
            c = s.charAt(++i)
        );     
        return [s.substring(0,i), s.substring(i)]; //return [the string, what comes after it]
    }

    function decode2(s) {
        s = s.replace(/^\s+/m, ""); //remove whitespace from the beginning of the string
        var c = s.charAt(0);

        if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') //value is a number
            return decodeInt(s);
        if (c == "'" || c == '"') //value is a string
            return decodeString(s);
        if (c == '{') //value is an object
            return decodeObject(s);

        if (charIsLetter(c))
            return decodeImproperString(s);

        throw "Unexpected character " + c + " at:" + s;
    }


    return {
        decode: function(s) {
            var result = decode2(s);
            return result[0];
        }
    };
})();
```

Now that we've got a way to parse the json, we need a way to find the deepest child. The way I went about doing this is a recursive function that returns the depth of it's children, 0 if it has no object as a child. It increments this depth for it's children and returns the child with the maximum depth.

```
function deepestObject(ob) {
    var ar = []; //array of objects and their depth

    for (var key in ob) {
        if (ob.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (Object.toType(ob[key]) == "object") {
                var child = deepestObject(ob[key]);
                child.depth++;
                ar.push(child);
            }
        }
    }

    var max = {depth: 0, children: ob};
    for (var i=0; i<ar.length;i++) {
        if (ar[i].depth > max.depth)
            max = ar[i];
    }

    return max;
}
```

I use a helper function is this, `Object.toType`. This is a wonderful function thought up by Angus Croll at [the Javascript Weblog](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/).

```
Object.toType = function(obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-z|A-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}
```

The deepestObject function doesn't return multiple children if they have the same depth though, this can be changed by using the following instead:

```
function deepestObject(ob) {
    var ar = []; //array of objects and their depth

    for (var key in ob) {
        if (ob.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (Object.toType(ob[key]) == "object") {
                var children = deepestObject(ob[key]); //array of deepest children
                for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) { //for each child
                    var child = children[i];
                    //console.log(child)
                    child.depth++;
                    ar.push(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var max = [{depth: 0, children: ob}];
    for (var i=0; i<ar.length;i++) {
        if (ar[i].depth > max[0].depth)
            max = [ar[i]];
        else if (ar[i].depth == max[0].depth)
            max.push(ar[i]);
    }

    return max;
}
```

You can see both working here: [single child](http://jsfiddle.net/7jJv3/33/) and [mulitple child](http://jsfiddle.net/7jJv3/36/).